# Import error: No module named tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, tkinter, python-import

I'm attempting to build graphics for a calculator I made, but I'm getting an error saying that there's no module tkinter. How do I fix my code so that it correctly imports tkinter?

```
import sys
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

root.title('Calculator')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: from Tkinter import *  - capitalization?

Comment: @flyingmeatball: The [python-3.x] tag suggests that it is Python 3, which uses the `tkinter` (all lower case) module.

Comment: touche - only ever used it in 2.7

Comment: If it's not a capitalization problem, you might need to [install tkinter](https://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/How_to_install_Tkinter).

Comment: Always include error messages and if possibly relevant, the entire traceback.  For any question about interacting with anything outside of Python, include the OS and version.

Comment: The Install Tkinter wiki page two have referenced is about a decade old.  Python.org has a new page for OSX.  The linux stuff might still be good.  But to repeat, identify your system.

Answer (score 4):

Check what python version you have

If you have python 3x:

```
from tkinter import *
```

If you have python 2x

```
from Tkinter import *
```

If both of those do not work, reinstall tkinter.

[Click here to install tkinter](https://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/How_to_install_Tkinter)